# How to get all session details from PMCMD in informatica when the workflow is a concurrent workflow

Tags: putty, informatica

I have configured the workflow as a concurrent workflow with same instance name and tried to retrieve the details using getsessionstatistics/gettaskdetails. Since it is a concurrent workflow, I am not able to get the details of all session using PMCMD in a shell script. And I saw one command in Informatica documentation as "getTaskDetailsEx". If I run this in putty, it is showing ERROR: Unknown command [gettaskdetailex]. I have tried with all lower cases also.

Can someone please suggest how to get details using "gettaskdetailex" or any other way to get all session details of concurrent workflow

Comment: have you tried `-runinsname`/`-rn`
runInsName
Name of the workflow run instance that contains the task. Use this option if you are running concurrent workflows.

Comment: Thank you Koushik Roy. Now I can able to get session details. I have this script in post session success command. If I run this through informatica (2 session pararelly) , the session is in running state and it is waiting for the child process of the shell command to exit. If I run the same in putty, it is working fine ( 1 session per script). Could you please share your thoughts on this